# Link tables and combine columns between them

Tags: join, crystal-reports

My single dataset (generated from a large spreadsheet) is split into multiple tables. The relevant information is the dates and a numerical value assigned to them.

The data is organized as such on each table:

```
Start Date | End Date | Return Value
    A1     |     B1   |      C1
    A2     |     B2   |      C2
    A3     |     B2   |      C3
```

The start and end dates are always quarter start and quarter end dates. The value C is always numeric. Each table represents a specific account. Some of these tables don't start until later dates (So Table 4 might have a start date equal to A3, for example).

I would like to group up these tables so the final report is organized as such:

```
Date range A1 - B1
Table1.C1 | calc(Table1.C1)
Table2.C1 | calc(Table2.C1)
Table3.C1 | calc(Table3.C1)
etc.
```

And on each detail line where TableX.CY is listed, perform relevant calculations using formulas.

The formulas I've already figured out and gotten sorted, but I'm lost at the best way to refer to each table without creating brand new formulas per table. IE, I don't want to create calcTable1(Table1.C1), calcTable2(Table2.C1), and so on, since there are over 40 tables in this.

How can I link these tables together so that the result set that CR is working with can be easily organized to produce this sort of report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link tables in the *Database Fields -> Database Expert -> Links* tab.

If you wish to perform these calculations via SQL before they even reach the report, you can do so in the Database Expert by using the Add Command option to write your on SQL formulas.

[image]

---

Otherwise you want to group based on a date range. So you should probably first create a formula to return the format `Date range A1 - B1`. Then create a group based on that formula you just made.

To add a group, go to *Insert -> Group* and select your formula as the subject of the Grouped By field.

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize there was an ability to define a SQL command in the database expert. This solves all my problems with a simple UNION. Thank you.